# AAPT: error: expected color reference but got (raw string) null

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I needed to hide the default overflow icon (3 dots) so I wrote the code below. I was working fine until I updated android studio yesterday, after that its giving me this error:

```
D:\Android Projects\myapp\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml:18:5-21:13: AAPT: error: expected color reference but got (raw string) null.
```

Here's the code:

```
<style name="MaterialTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDarkColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/secondaryColor</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/CustomActionOverflowButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomActionOverflowButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:width">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:src">null</item>
</style>
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help!

Comment: in your _CustomActionOverflowButtonStyle_, try adding a color to "android:src" instead of null and see if that makes any difference. If it does and you want to make sure that there's no color in your view, add a transparent color instead like #00000000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change this

```
<item name="android:src">null</item>
```

to

```
<item name="android:src">@null</item>
```